# Как правильно написать программу по вычислению координат нескольких объектов в окне и выводу объектов на экран?

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Хочу написать программу которая должна вычислять координаты нескольких объектов в окне и выводить объекты на экран.
Сейчас я пытаюсь понять, как сделать это правильно.
Я хочу сделать это так:

1. один класс рассчитывает все изменения координат всех объектов и других атрибутов.
2. второй класс запустить в ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ поток. Он берёт готовые координаты объектов (и их атрибуты) и, не обращая внимания на первый поток перерисовывает экран с определённой частотой.

Мне кажется, что это логичная структура.
Подскажите, стоит ли так делать. Или появятся проблемы.
В таком случае, какой способ использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: В целом подход правильный. Будет вопрос с синхронизацией - что если во время отрисовки объект меняет свои координаты, или, хуже того, пропадает или появляется новый.

Comment: Расскажите подробнее про первый класс. Как часто он будет пересчитывать координаты? От чего это зависит?

Comment: @Kromster , мне это и нужно. Первый класс создаёт новые объекты, удаляет, перемещает, изменяет размер. А второй класс (10 раз в сек. например) смотрит на свежий список объектов (на координаты и атрибуты) и выводит их на экран. Снова и снова

Comment: @Mark Tiukov, тут несколько случаев. Координаты меняются тогда когда я указываю объекту куда двигаться. Он начинает движение и движется с определённой скоростью пока не достигнет цели. Но пока я не указал объекту цель он стоит на месте, но меняет  свой размер (пульсирует). Его тоже постоянно нужно перерисовывать. И таких объектов несколько десятков

Comment: Вот туториал с важной информацией про взаимодействие потоков при работе со Swing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html А здесь про нюансы отрисовки https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html Возможно, вам стоит почитать что-то вроде Killer Game Programming in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом подход правильный. Будет вопрос с синхронизацией - когда в момент отрисовки объект меняет свои координаты, или, хуже того, пропадает или появляется новый (вызывая перестроение коллекции). Тут или использовать какие-то способы синхронизации доступа (пока рисуем, не обновляем) или какую-нибудь двойную буферизацию (обновляем и откладываем результаты для отрисовки).

В вашем случае, может быть проще гарантировать неизменный массив объектов. Т.е. выделить вначале, например, 10000 элементов, отметить их все "выключенными". Далее обновлять объекты, добалять путем "включения" объекта, а удалять - "выключением". При таком подходе, вы можете стабильно рисовать из этого массива. В отрисовке просто пропускайте "выключенные" объекты. Даже если отрисовка совпадет по времени с обновлением, максимум, что вы получите - отрисовку объекта с несовпадающими компонентами (при частом обновлении и небольших дельтах, это будет незаметно).

Comment: Зачем делать выключенные объекты и ограничение на их количество?! Существуют array lists и многие другие контейнеры

Comment: @Kromster, выше в коменте я написал почему отказываюсь от много поточности. Теперь думаю как правильно организовать цикличность пересчёта координат. Например, так: 1) создаю объект Timer с определённой частотой. И стартую его. 2) С каждым тиком таймера выполняю перерасчёт координат и атрибутов. 3) После пересчёта выполняю перерисовку. Подскажите, это правильный подход для решения данной задачи?

Comment: @MarkTiukov не знаю как в Java, но в более низкоуровневых языках, при изменении размера коллекции-обертки над массивом, она может быть перемещена в другое место в памяти, и, если отрисовка шла напрямую, то есть риск получить краш доступа к невалидной памяти.

Comment: @pumaex если у вас обновление и перерисовка на одном таймере, то никакого смысла городить огород нету. Просто вызывайте их друг за другом и все.

Comment: @Kromster делать отрисовку напрямую плохо энивей, надо отделять интерфейс от логики. Поэтому при правильном подходе не должно возникнуть упомянутой Вами ошибки

Comment: @MarkTiukov все зависит от деталей, которые ТС держит в секрете )

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас не слишком большое количество объектов, я бы не советовал использовать многопоточность. Только в крайнем случае, если у вас не получится оптимизировать отрисовку и лаги будут сохраняться, то имеет смысл попробовать.

В таком случае подумайте о использовании метода wait() у потока, чтобы синхронизировать изменения и отрисовку (чтобы отрисовка начиналась только после завершения цикла изменения).

Без многопоточности просто храните все объекты в каком-нибудь контейнере, в зависимости от структуры ( ArrayList<> — классика), пробегайтесь по нему, изменяя всё, что надо, потом вторым пробегом - отрисовка. Играясь с фпс можно уменьшить лаги.

Comment: наверное откажусь от многопоточности. Я только начинаю изучать java поэтому плохо ориентируюсь. Подумал и теперь не вижу смысла в отдельном потоке. Нужно как-то организовать цикличность пересчёта координат, а в конце пересчёта всё перерисовать. Понял, что был не прав.

Comment: @pumaex На мой взгляд, самая грамотная организация: сделать у объекта метод update() с нужными для него аргументами и в цикле по контейнеру всех объектов вызывать данный метод

Comment: попытаюсь так и сделать. Выше в коментарии предложил способ организации  частоты цикличности. Это нормальный способ?

Comment: @pumaex всмл сначала все изменить, потом отрисовать? Да, это даже правильнее. Стоит отделять интерфейс от логики

Comment: @ Mark Tiukov, вот такой способ подойдёт? 1) создаю объект Timer с определённой частотой. И стартую его. 2) С каждым тиком таймера выполняю перерасчёт координат и атрибутов. 3) После пересчёта выполняю перерисовку.

Comment: @pumaex нет. Не нужно дергать систему каждый тик. Это лишняя нагрузка на систему. Почитайте про FPS. Заводите переменную _fps - число кадров в секунду. Для начала попробуйте 60. После перерисовки нужно затормозить данный поток на 1000/FPS ( это 1000 миллисекунд). В простых проектах отрисовка очень быстро происходит и 60 фпс должно хватить. Изменяйте, что получить требуемую плавность.

Comment: @ Mark Tiukov, так я же вроде тоже самое написал.  1) создаю объект Timer с определённой частотой. Т.е. Timer тикает, например, 10 раз в сек. Или я чего-то не понял про таймер?

Comment: @pumaex мне кажется, Timer -- это плохо, если не нужно знать само значение времени. Просто потому что это лишний объект => нагрузка. Вроде как Timer это отдельный поток, что еще большая лишняя нагрузка.